# Exception in thread "main" "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element" BUT it is required to allow both test-classes and test-class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am getting an Exception while running the following code :

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestClassesType.class , TestClassType.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
System.out.println("XMLFILE ==  " + xmlFilePath);
JAXBElement tcstJaxb = (JAXBElement) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(xmlFilePath));
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"test-class"). Expected elements are <{}test-classes>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
```

I have speified both TestClassesType.class , TestClassType.class in code segment : `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestClassesType.class , TestClassType.class);` But still When some xml starts with test-classes it is able to unmarshall it but classes that starts with test-class , it is unable to unmarshall it and throws the above Exception.
Classes used :
TestClassesType

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "test-classesType", propOrder = {
    "testClass"
})
public class TestClassesType {

    @XmlElement(name = "test-class")
    protected List<TestClassType> testClass;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the testClass property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the testClass property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getTestClass().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link TestClassType }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<TestClassType> getTestClass() {
        if (testClass == null) {
            testClass = new ArrayList<TestClassType>();
        }
        return this.testClass;
    }

}
```

TestClassType :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "test-classType", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
public class TestClassType {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "test-method", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getContent().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TestMethodType }{@code >}
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

}
```

I have a few xmls that start with test-classes and some that starts with test-class tag. I want to allow both of these. Is there any way to accomplish this?

The ObjectFactory class so generated is the one below :

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _TestClasses_QNAME = new QName("", "test-classes");
    private final static QName _TestClassTypeTestMethod_QNAME = new QName("", "test-method");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.jaxb.scenario
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link TestClassesType }
     * 
     */
    public TestClassesType createTestClassesType() {
        return new TestClassesType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ParamsType }
     * 
     */
    public ParamsType createParamsType() {
        return new ParamsType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link TestCaseType }
     * 
     */
    public TestCaseType createTestCaseType() {
        return new TestCaseType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link TestClassType }
     * 
     */
    public TestClassType createTestClassType() {
        return new TestClassType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link AssertType }
     * 
     */
    public AssertType createAssertType() {
        return new AssertType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link TestMethodType }
     * 
     */
    public TestMethodType createTestMethodType() {
        return new TestMethodType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link AssertsType }
     * 
     */
    public AssertsType createAssertsType() {
        return new AssertsType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ParamType }
     * 
     */
    public ParamType createParamType() {
        return new ParamType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TestClassesType }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "test-classes")
    public JAXBElement<TestClassesType> createTestClasses(TestClassesType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<TestClassesType>(_TestClasses_QNAME, TestClassesType.class, null, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TestMethodType }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "test-method", scope = TestClassType.class)
    public JAXBElement<TestMethodType> createTestClassTypeTestMethod(TestMethodType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<TestMethodType>(_TestClassTypeTestMethod_QNAME, TestMethodType.class, TestClassType.class, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the xml that should be unmarshaled? anyway into the xml there is a tag `<test-class>` that should be called `<test-classes>`

Comment: I want to allow both <test-class> and <test-classes> as some xmls starts with <test-classes> and others with <test-class>. My requirement is that the code unmarshals both kinds of xmls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `test-class` element correspond to an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on the `ObjectFactory` class (or the class you have annotated with `@XmlRegistry`?  If so you will need to include it when you bootstrap your `JAXBContext`.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
```

If you generated your model from an XML Schema, the `ObjectFactory` class is the only one you need to pass in to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

Comment: I have added ObjectFactory class in the question. It doesn't have any XmlElementDecl with it. Is it necessary to have @XmlElementDecl with test-class. Also there is some QName declaration : private final static QName _TestClasses_QNAME = new QName("", "test-classes"); .. What is its use?

Comment: Added a QName and method similar to test-classes in ObjectFactory class and passed ObjectFactory.class in JAXBContext solved my issue.